# Adobe Echosign Integration In PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, adobe, echosign

I am developing a website where i need to integrate adobe echo sign in my Form. You may visit this [link](http://maverickpreviews.com/design/sfpowerboats/booking-page.html) to check the form (Step 3).

What i am trying to do is to let the renter enter his/her signature directly to my form and automatically create SIGNED PDF. We will be using echosign to accomplish this feature. But when i tried to browse their API documentation, i can't find what i'm looking for.

Can anyone suggest me alternatives of this feature just in case this feature is not available in Adobe Echo Sign?

Answer (score 0):

After the user has filled in all the information, you can generate a PDF and host it for signing. This is achievable through the following two endpoints: POST /agreements and followed by a GET /agreements/{agreementId}/signingUrls. For more details, you can refer the API documentation at [https://secure.na1.echosign.com/public/docs/restapi/v5#!/agreements](https://secure.na1.echosign.com/public/docs/restapi/v5#!/agreements/)/. Let me know if this helps. Thanks